# Subject-verb agreement 'It makes me feel'

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement, learning

I'm a bit confused with the subject-verb agreement of this phrase:

> It makes me feel like something.

Why is the word "feel" not "feels" since "me" is singular?

Comment: Might need some context for this one. Is that the entire sentence? They could be expressing that doing an action makes them feel like they are something, rather than feeling like they are nothing?

Comment: ***feel*** there is an "unmarked infinitive" (the "marked" form being ***to feel***), so it doesn't change. Thus it's just the same form in ***We make** him **feel** uncomfortable* and ***He makes** them **feel** uncomfortable* (where the ***make / makes*** choice reflects the different subject nouns ***we / he***).

Comment: @Smock: More context wouldn't make any different to the grammatical point being queried. It's *always* an unmarked infinitive, regardless of additional context.

Comment: True (you should make your comment an answer by the way). I guess I just felt the sentence felt very awkward on its own and wanted more context for me to understand it as a whole, but I guess that's outside the scope of the question perhaps.